# Where should a foreign interested party in a civil case seek a lawyer?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom

A civil case is in progress in the UK. Someone involved in the case as an interested party wants to make a motion about it, but is a US citizen living in the US.

Should they get a lawyer at home in the US, or should they get one in the UK jurisdiction where the case is being handled?

Comment: This is not a request for specific advice. It's about hiring a lawyer, which is exactly what people are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should get a lawyer in the UK jurisdiction where the case is being handled. To file a motion in a case pending before a tribunal one needs to be admitted to the practice of law before that tribunal.